# $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) = X$ implies that $f= g $ as morphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $X,Y$ be schemes over $S$ and assumed $Y/S$ is separated and $X$ reduced. Let $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ denote the equalizer of $f$ and $g$. By base change to an affine open subset $U$ of $X$, I can show that the map

$$\operatorname{Eq}(f|_U,g|_U) = \operatorname{Eq}(f,g) \cap U \longrightarrow U$$

is an isomorphism and since $U$ was arbitrary, thus we have that $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) \cong X$.

> > **My questions are:**
> >
> > 1. How does this imply that $f = g$ ***as morphisms of schemes***?
> > 2. This is possibly stupid but isn't there a difference between saying $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) = X$ and $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g) \cong X$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is pure abstract nonsense:

> The equaliser of a parallel pair $f_0, f_1 : X \to Y$ is an isomorphism $e : E \to X$ if and only if $f_0 = f_1$.

Indeed, if $e$ is the equaliser, then $f_0 \circ e = f_1 \circ e$; and if $e$ is an isomorphism (or even just an epimorphism!), then we can cancel $e$ and get $f_0 = f_1$. Conversely, if $f_0 = f_1$, then $\mathrm{id} : X \to X$ is an equaliser (of course!), but equalisers are unique up to unique isomorphism, so any other equaliser of $f_0$ and $f_1$ must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks Zhen for your answer. Though, do you have any thoughts for 2) in my question above? Thanks.

Comment: (2) doesn't make sense. It's an abuse of notation to refer to an equaliser as an _object_; equalisers are morphisms.

Comment: To be maximally explicit, $\operatorname{Eq}(f,g)$ consists of an object $E$ and a morphism $eq: E \to X$ satisfying some universal property (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalizer_%28mathematics%29)). My new question is: what is the difference between $E = X$ and $E \cong X$?

Comment: It's not important. What's important is whether the morphism $E \to X$ is an isomorphism or not.